# DNS Problems (NIGHTMARES!) with BIND and Virtualmin

Tags: linux, ubuntu, domain-name-system, bind, nameserver

I have a webserver (Ubuntu 12.04 with LAMP) using Virtualmin / Webmin. Because I just moved from a  Cpanel system, I am having a nightmare configuring the DNS!

Using intoDNS.com, the failed reports are:

```
Mismatched NS records   WARNING: One or more of your nameservers did not return any of your NS records.
DNS servers responded   ERROR: One or more of your nameservers did not respond: The ones that did not respond are: 123.123.123.123 213.251.188.141x
Multiple Nameservers    ERROR: Looks like you have less than 2 nameservers. According to RFC2182 section 5 you must have at least 3 nameservers, and no more than 7. Having 2 nameservers is also ok by me.
Missing nameservers 
  reported by your nameserver   You should already know that your NS records at your nameservers are missing, so here it is again: 
                                    ns1.mydomain.com. sdns2.ovh.net. 
SOA record  No valid SOA record came back!
MX Records
WWW A Record     ERROR: I could not get any A records for www.mydomain.com!
```

**Step-by-Step of my Attempt**

In my domain registrar (Namecheap), I registered `ns1.mydomain.com` as a nameserver, pointing to the IP address of my web server which is running `bind9`. The domain is setup with DNS `ns1.mydomain.com` and `sdns2.ovh.net`. `sdns2.ovh.net` is a secondary DNS server (SLAVE and pointing `mydomain.com` to the IP address of my web server)

**Webserver domain**: `mydomain.com`

**Webserver hostname**: `ns4000000.ip-123-123-123.net`

**Webserver IP**: `123.123.123.123`

Under Virtualmin, I edited the default Virtual server template,

- BIND DNS records for new domains: `ns1.mydomain.com`
- Master DNS server hostname: `ns1.mydomain.com`

Next I created a Virtual server using that server template.

This is what I've done but its still not working! Any ideas? I've been stuck for days, thank you for all your help!

**service bind9 status**

```
* bind9 is running
```

**lsof -i :53**

```
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
named   6966 bind   20u  IPv6 338583      0t0  TCP *:domain (LISTEN)
named   6966 bind   21u  IPv4 338588      0t0  TCP localhost.localdomain:domain (LISTEN)
named   6966 bind   22u  IPv4 338590      0t0  TCP ns4000000.ip-123-123-123.net:domain (LISTEN)
named   6966 bind  512u  IPv6 338582      0t0  UDP *:domain
named   6966 bind  513u  IPv4 338587      0t0  UDP localhost.localdomain:domain
named   6966 bind  514u  IPv4 338589      0t0  UDP ns4000000.ip-123-123-123.net:domain
```

**/etc/resolv.con**

*(Not sure how `213.186.33.99` got here)*

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
nameserver 213.186.33.99
search ovh.net
```

**host 123.123.123.123** *(my web server's IP)*

```
13.60.245.198.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer ns4000000.ip-123-123-123.net.
```

**nslookup 213.186.33.99**

```
Server:         127.0.0.1
Address:        127.0.0.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
99.33.186.213.in-addr.arpa      name = cdns.ovh.net.

Authoritative answers can be found from:
33.186.213.in-addr.arpa nameserver = ns.ovh.net.
33.186.213.in-addr.arpa nameserver = dns.ovh.net.
```

**nslookup ns1.mydomain.com**

```
;; Got SERVFAIL reply from 127.0.0.1, trying next server
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

**nslookup ns2.mydomain.com**

```
;; Got SERVFAIL reply from 127.0.0.1, trying next server
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

**nslookup www.mydomain.com**

```
;; Got SERVFAIL reply from 127.0.0.1, trying next server
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

**dig mydomain.com**

```
; <<>> DiG 9.8.1-P1 <<>> mydomain.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 43540
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;mydomain.com.                  IN      A

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Thu Oct 11 11:30:09 2012
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 30
```

**dig ns1.mydomain.com**

```
; <<>> DiG 9.8.1-P1 <<>> ns1.mydomain.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 31254
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;ns1.mydomain.com.              IN      A

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Thu Oct 11 11:30:16 2012
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 34
```

**/etc/bind/named.conf**

```
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.options";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.local";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.default-zones";
```

**/etc/bind/named.conf.default-zones**

```
zone "." {
    type hint;
    file "/etc/bind/db.root";
};

zone "localhost" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/db.local";
};

zone "127.in-addr.arpa" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/db.127";
};

zone "0.in-addr.arpa" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/db.0";
};

zone "255.in-addr.arpa" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/db.255";
};
```

**/etc/bind/named.conf.local**

```
zone "mydomain.com" {
    type master;
    file "/var/lib/bind/mydomain.com.hosts";
    allow-transfer {
        127.0.0.1;
        localnets;
        };
    };
```

**/etc/bind/named.conf.options**

```
options {
    directory "/var/cache/bind";

    dnssec-validation auto;

    auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
    listen-on-v6 { any; };
//  allow-recursion { 127.0.0.1; };
//  transfer-source;
};
```

**named-checkconf -z**

```
zone mydomain.com/IN: loaded serial 1349965194
zone localhost/IN: loaded serial 2
zone 127.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
zone 0.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
zone 255.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
```

**iptables -L**

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:20000
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:webmin
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:imaps
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:imap2
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:pop3s
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:pop3
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ftp-data
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ftp
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:domain
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:submission
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:smtp
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Comment: Looks like you've posted every possible detail _except_ the relevant information. `/var/lib/bind/mydomain.com.hosts` is where it said the problem was.

Comment: Thanks, somehow virtualmin created the last line that had just an IP. I removed that line and named-checkconf -z no longer gave that error (updated post too). Restarted `bind` and now `dig mydomain.com` is giving a reponse!

Comment: OK, so does that mean everything's working?

Comment: Yes it is! The site is now accessible. Thank you for helping Michael!

Comment: OK, I've made it a full answer so you can accept it which marks it as resolved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your output from `named-checkconf -z` indicated that there was a syntax error in `/var/lib/bind/mydomain.com.hosts`, the only file you didn't actually post. Check the file and fix any errors in it.

Answer (score 1):

to debug a server problem, always check the logs after a restart of a service:

>

> tail -f /var/log/messages

or

> tail -f /var/log/syslog

ctrl+C to abort

or show only the last 20 records of syslog

> tail -n 20 /var/log/syslog